# PLA Warps despite every effort to prevent it

Tags: pla, warping, creality-ender-5

I am using a Creality Ender 5 with a tempered glass bed. I could say that I am a seasoned 3D printing hobbyist but I am really out of ideas in this case. Currently I am using a grey colored PLA that was working rather fine (not as good as my Hatchbox, but that ran out). I set my bed temperature to 60 °C as always, even used a raft to improve adhesion. Since the print I am trying to accomplish is not very tall, and I detest even the slightest warping, I disabled the cooling fan for most of my print, and crank it to half way up in the middle. I am using a custom printed nozzle shroud, but it doesn’t matter in this case because the print warped before halfway to a point that I have never encountered even back in the day when I would use cooling fan on every layer. It is truly terrifying and I need some advice. Thanks!

Some stats:

- Bed: 60 °C
- Nozzle: 200 °C for 1st layer, 185 °C for the rest
- Fan: 50 % at layer 50, 0 % all before
- Raft: yes
- Resolution: 0.2 mm

Comment: PLA doesn't shrink much, but the difference between first layer and consecutive layers is pretty large, more than I've seen (usually it is about 5 °C), maybe you should bring the first layer temp closer to the normal printing temperature or vice versa and ditch the raft in favor of a brim.

Comment: See my question https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/q/13892/11157 and the linked question - have you tried switching to outer walls first? I don't understand why but it helps a lot with this for me.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE It does make some sense, I will try it out.